# How to use Record key as index for function arg type?

Tags: typescript

I currently have :

```js
const useFormTransform = <T>(
  formValues: T,
  transform: Partial<Record<keyof T, (value: T[keyof T]) => any>>,
) => ...
```

That is used like this :

```js
type Line = { id?: string; fromQuantity: number };
const line: Line = { id: 'abc', fromQuantity: 123 };

useFormTransform(
  line,
  {
    id: f => f,
    fromQuantity: f => transformNumber(Number(f)),
  },
);
```

I would like to get something like `Record<keyof T as U, (value: U) => any>` for the `transform` arg so the `value` is not `string | undefined | number` but `number` since `typeof line['fromQuantity'] === 'number'`

I tries many things but I can't get it to work.

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `Record` you will need a custom mapped type:

```
const useFormTransform = <T, U extends keyof T>(
  formValues: T,
    transform: {
      [P in keyof T]: (value: T[P]) => T[P]
  },
) => {
    return null!;
}


type Line = { id?: string; fromQuantity: number };
const line: Line = { id: 'abc', fromQuantity: 123 };

useFormTransform(
  line,
  {
    id: f => f,
    fromQuantity: f => f + 1,
  },
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgMRAJwLYBU0ENIBm6GMAvDADxYA0MAqjIgB5SJgAmEMA1ogJ4gCMLAD4AFAFgAUDBhFMANVwAbOIggAuYdWmzZUPIWJaA3rr2yA2gAUYASzA9+g4QF0tYgG4q1WrDdcASjIRYQDzAF8dKWDSULMZPTREKDg0RzA4ZWUAQgBuaQjpYqkoPgAHRBgAGQcq8hN7dgB+LWg0BwBzPLk0EAwARTh8KDsyrUyMACNENBgIgqlQSFhlOq1asHqYRrt2LQByXCngA9oCPsHhsFHxmABGACYAZnnF6QQUYhx8CHkMSSJNZbaKyBIWPZaIRxOSgvQXfpDEZjPhQkJyGAAagecKi0kCeSAA)

Comment: It works just great... Thank you Titian ! So simple :)